# How to remove a list item using onclick()

Tags: javascript

I have this list and onclick function but it won't work.

```js
const trash = document.querySelector(".fa-trash");

trash.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("you clicked me");
  list.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<ul id="my_ul">
  <li>
    <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Eat
  </li>
  <li>
    <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Drink
  </li>
  <li>
    <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Sleep
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: with the given code above, your fa-trash has no width therefore you cannot click on it since it visually does not exist. Also `querySelector` only return the first element. `list` is also undefined in the above code

Comment: yes you can click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use event delegation on the `<ul>` element.
2. You can directly get the `<li>` element (which is the grandparent of the trash icon) and call [`Element#remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).

```js
const list = document.getElementById("my_ul");
list.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches(".fa-trash")) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
<ul id="my_ul">
  <li>
    <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Eat
  </li>
  <li>
    <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Drink
  </li>
  <li>
    <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Sleep
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could also use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest if IE is not supported

Comment: IE also doesn't support `Element.prototype.remove`. But IE is also completely irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnMo Glad to help.